# Django generic ChoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-forms, choicefield

I want a generic list of choices in my form.
In the 
**devices.py**

```
def get_devices():
    api_url = api_url_base
    response = requests.get(api_url,headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
    else:
        return None

#######################################
devices_infos = get_devices()

if devices_infos is not None:
    print('Voici les devices: ')
    for each in devices_infos['data']:
        device_name =  (each['name'])
        for k in range(len(devices_infos['data'])):
            mes_choix = ("(%s, ('%s'))," % (k,device_name ))

else:
    print("[!] Request failed")
```

It returns me my 2 devices like that

```
(0, ('Erics phone')),
(1, ('mySensor001')),
```

In **forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from alertes.devices import *
class NameForm(forms.Form):
    nom_alerte = forms.CharField(label='Nom Alerte', max_length=100)
    devices = forms.ChoiceField(label='Liste devices', choices=mes_choix, required=False)
    user_mail = forms.EmailField(label = 'Email a envoyer', max_length=100)
```

Here, i would have in the devices label, a list of choice like

```
Erics phone
mySensor001
```

But i got the **need more than 1 value to unpack** error

Comment: If you get an error, you need to show the whole thing.

Comment: @DanielRoseman i got this error
`ValueError at /alertes/sep/
need more than 1 value to unpack
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/alertes/sep/
Django Version: 1.11.8
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: 
need more than 1 value to unpack
Exception Location: /Users/kebson/Work/venv_rule_eng/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py in _choice_has_empty_value, line 673
Python Executable: /Users/kebson/Work/venv_rule_eng/bin/python`

Comment: the error is about what i describe above. i just want to generate the items of my choices list via a file named devices.py where i generate a list of items, and render it to the forms.py. But i got that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not creating a list of choices at all; you simply define a single string, `mes_choix`, which contains a single choice description. Instead you need a list or tuple of choices, each entry of which contains a tuple of (id, name).

```
if devices_infos is not None:
    mes_choix = [(i, device['name']) for i, device in enumerate(devices_infos['data'])]
```

Comment: it works perfectly.  My only matter is why it ddidn't create a list of choices. Because the file generated this 2 line: 
` (0, ('Erics phone')),
(1, ('mySensor001')),`
Thanks you btw